# How to open messages from Android App using startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, floating-action-button, startactivityforresult

I want to use a floating action button for opening a new message from my android phone. I have used startActivityForResult() method for successfully opening settings. But when I use the same for opening messages, this method doesn't seem to work. I have also attached my code to be more clear.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS),0);
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try something like this :**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
              sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
              startActivityForResult(sendIntent , 0);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But can you do me a favor? I am actually trying to understand the code. So can you please provide me a code to open contacts from the startActivityForResult() method, so that I can study them both and figure out the difference. Though I found various examples on the internet but I didn't find anyone using this method.

Comment: Hi there, 
you need to change the `data` and the `action` correspondingly for contact. Here it's a intent to pick contact . 

`Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);`

Comment: I exactly did that earlier(thanks to stackoverflow), but facing issues with PICK_CONTACT parameter. Error shows "cannot resolve symbol PICK_CONTACT". Is there anything I should import in my java file?

Comment: PICK_CONTACT is a int which is nothing but your requestCode . 
put this `private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 10 ;` as a global initialization .

Comment: Tried this one. But sadly my application stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

You can send this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Note that in this case `startActivityForResult` is not necessary, because the second activity is not supposed to return a value to the first one.